# ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate - Error is coming while calling viewcomponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, view-components

I am creating viewcomponents and below are my all code..but when I call this viewcomponent, I am getting error like below..so any one can help me to solve this as well as explain me what exactly issue is.

The error is :

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'PerfumeStore.Data.Models.ShoppingCart' while attempting to activate
> 'PerfumeStore.ViewComponents.ShoppingCartSummaryViewComponent'.

First of all I have created one folder with name ViewComponents in that I have created new class with name ShoppingCartSummaryViewComponent.cs and below is code of that.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PerfumeStore.Data.Models;
using PerfumeStore.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PerfumeStore.ViewComponents
{
    public class ShoppingCartSummaryViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ShoppingCart _shoppingCart;
        public ShoppingCartSummaryViewComponent(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
        {
            _shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            var items = _shoppingCart.GetShoppingCartItems();
            _shoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems = items;

            var shoppingCartViewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
            {
                ShoppingCart = _shoppingCart,
                ShoppingCartTotal = _shoppingCart.GetShoppingCartTotal()
            };

            return View(shoppingCartViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Now cshtml file is below in this path : in Views / Shared / Components / ShoppingCartSummary /Default.cshtml

```
@model ShoppingCartViewModel

@if (Model.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems.Count > 0)
{
    <li>
        <a asp-controller="ShoppingCart">
            <span class="glphyicon glphyicon-shopping-cart"></span>
            <span id="cart-status">
                @Model.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems.Count
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

Now in my _Layout.cshtml file I am calling this viewcomponent in this way.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("ShoppingCartSummary")
            </ul>
        </div>
```

But I am getting this error :

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'PerfumeStore.Data.Models.ShoppingCart' while attempting to activate 'PerfumeStore.ViewComponents.ShoppingCartSummaryViewComponent'.

Thanks

Comment: Have you registered `ShoppingCart` as a dependency somewhere?

Comment: @PlamenYordanov No I have not registered..should I register that in startup.cs and if yes then what will be code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Dependending on your dependency lifecycle (transient, scoped, singleton) you can register it in your `Startup.cs` as:

*Transient*:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
```

*Scoped*:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
```

*Singleton*:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
```

You can read more in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#register-groups-of-services-with-extension-methods)

*Note: If your `ShoppingCart` class does not have an interface you can ommit the base type when registering- `services.AddTransient<MyDependency>();`*

Comment: Yes..my shoopingcart class has not interface, so I can add this in startup.cs like this way..

 services.AddTransient<ShoppingCart>();

is this ok ?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you should also consider the appropriate lifetime for the `ShoppingCart` instances.

Comment: ..Yes..I will consider that..many Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Register class at `ConfigureService` method in `Startup.cs` file

```cs
services.AddScoped<ShoppingCart>();
```